# Force Maven to rebuild local dependencies

Tags: maven

I have two modules at the same hierarchy level, each a child of the same parent `pom.xml`: foo (jar) and bar (war). foo is a dependency of bar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>parentArtifact</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run `mvn install` in bar, foo does not get rebuilt. It does if I run a build at the parentArtifact level but I don't want to do it, for speed (there are other modules).

How can I force a rebuild of foo every time a build is run in bar?

Comment: I don't understand because `but I don't want to do it, for speed (there are other modules).` but in the title you've written: `to rebuild..` so go to the root level and rebuilt it via `mvn clean package` or use `mvn clean verify` if you have integration tests.

Comment: there are 7 modules in the parent but I want to run only 2 (bar + its dependency foo)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the parent level and run

`mvn clean install -pl bar -am`

This will build `bar` and all dependencies of `bar`.

Comment: I am trying to do it at the sub-module level where other sub-modules are rebuilt if they are depenencies

Comment: I cannot be done at the submodule level. At least not with Maven alone.